# distinct strings value and concatenating the results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

i'm trying to distinct different string values of "comment" and "dates" and concatenate them in two different strings one for comments and one for reclamation dates I used $addToSet to distinct values but every time the concatenating is giving empty result
and this is m code :

```
     db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        b: "$type"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$root"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        r: "$root.situation",
        b: "$root.type"
      },
      cnt: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      total: {
        "$first": "$total"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      a: [
        {
          k: "$_id.r",
          v: "$cnt"
        }
      ],
      type: "$_id.b",
      total: "$total",
      _id: 0,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      d: {
        $arrayToObject: "$a"
      },
      type: 1,
      total: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      situation: {
        $push: "$d"
      },
      sum: {
        "$first": "$total"
      },
      //add to set of commets and dates
      comment: {
        $addToSet: "$comment"
      },
      daterec: {
        $addToSet: "$daterec"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      type: "$_id",
      sum: 1,
      "options": {
        $mergeObjects: "$situation"
      },
      //concatenating results
      comment: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$comment",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$value",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              {
                $concat: [
                  "$$value",
                  " ",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      daterec: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$daterec",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$value",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              {
                $concat: [
                  "$$value",
                  " ",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$options"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      options: 0,
      
    }
  },
  
])
```

and this is the output :

```
{
"after sales management": 4,
"comment": "",
"daterec": "",
"instock": 1,
"sum": 5,
"type": "pc"


}
```

its always giving "comment" and"daterec": empty while i want it to show the concatenating of distinct strings it should looks something like this :

```
{
    "after sales management": 4,
    "comment": "waiting for pieces waiting for approval nothing",
    "daterec": "1",//this is just an example beacause all dates are set to "1"
    "instock": 1,
    "sum": 5,
    "type": "pc"
  }
```

this is an example of my work with a collection example:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dB3xBFsIfun

PS : i think the problem is in the of using the $addToSet insite $group

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LPdB-MQ9KyU) what you are looking for? Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @ray es but i want it inside the other aggregation i want to show type names and count different situation. iwant the same ouputs that i posted but with cpmments and dates showing results

Comment: Folks:  Let's bring the question and answers back here to stackoverflow.   mongoplayground example is an optional nicety but does not replace the need to describe / annotate both the question and answer here.

Comment: Clarity:   You want to group by type AND situation and show concatenated comments and dates for each?   What are these other fields like "sum" and "instock" and the treatment of situation?  It might be good to show 3 input docs (2 with same type+date, 1 different) along with the desired output.

Comment: @Buzz instok is one of the situation the aggreagation shows every existing situation and numbers of items for example 4 phone are in stock and 2 are in aftee sales management and sum is the sum of every item in this case 6 phones so the sum is 6